# What does the flashing blue portion of the health bar mean?

Tags: salt

In [Salt](http://store.steampowered.com/app/327860/), sometimes after eating something, a portion of the health bar flashes blue. What does this mean?

[image: flashing blue health bar]

Comment: I don't have enough rep to create a Salt tag...

Comment: I have found that sleeping doesn't make it go away, but quitting to the main menu and then loading the game again will.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that in Salt, eating food causes you to regenerate health over time, and the flashing blue part of your health bar is how much health you will get from eating that item. The wiki at http://projectsalt.wikia.com/wiki/Health seems to imply this, but doesn't actually answer your question.

Comment: Hmmm, I can see the part about eating food regenerating health on that page, but I can't see the hunger bar mentioned anywhere there. I also can't see anything about it mentioned [here](http://projectsalt.wikia.com/wiki/Food). The bar has been flashing blue for a while now (several days). Perhaps it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is due to eating something that raises maximum health (e.g. Pristine Deer Meat). The increased maximum health seems to stick around forever while the game is loaded; I've tried sleeping for several days on end and the blue bar and my increase maximum health was still there. However, after quitting to the main menu and then loading the game again, I see that the flashing blue portion is gone and my maximum health along with it.